# socket.io connect to unix socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to connect to unix socket using socket.io-client, 
No success (mostly timeout, last sample - dns resolution error).

```
var clientio  = require('socket.io-client');
// i tried all variants here
//client=clientio.connect('port.io/',{'force new connection': true});
//client=clientio.connect('unix://port.io/',{'force new connection': true});
//client=clientio.connect('http//unix:port.io/',{'force new connection': true});

client.on('connect',connect);
```

Is there any way to connect socket.io client to unix socket ?

I checked server socket using `nc -U port.io`, it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this while looking for answers to similar question.

AFAIK `socket.io-client` depends on `engne.io-client`, which depends on `ws`, which contains this:

`var isUnixSocket = serverUrl.protocol === 'ws+unix:';`

See here: https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/4f99812b1095979afaad58865846b160334f3415/lib/WebSocket.js#L598.

So it looks like it might be possible to connect client through UNIX socket, as long as it is done in node.js (or something similar) - i don't think it is possible to do in a web browser.

<s>I did not try it, but maybe something like this will work:</s>

`var client=clientio.connect('ws+unix:/port.io',{'force new connection': true});`

**Update:** it looks like socket.io and engine.io really do not like UNIX domain sockets :(. To connect through UDS, direct use of `ws` module seems to be the only way, but then it will not know all the additional stuff that socket.io builds on top (like rooms and namespaces).

Comment: Last time it was urlparser, all other parts support unix socket,  i will check if anything changed since i looked before

Comment: same as long ago - it "fixes" url here https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/url.js#L41

Comment: You're right. But it looks like their "broken" `url` is used only here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/280246357908556dbe98f16d413e6b5030094485/lib/index.js#L44 which means that one could monkey patch socket.io-client by changing code of `lookup` function.

Comment: It is possible to override their `url` function using `mock-require` module. Unfotunately, they override protocol once again in https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/blob/master/lib/transports/websocket.js#L248. That, of course, too could be overriden, but then there's also a problem of specifying path... too many changes would be required :(.

Answer (score 1):

`socket.io` runs a specific protocol on top of a `webSocket` protocol which then runs on a plain TCP socket.  If you are trying to connect to a plain Unix socket, then you cannot use `socket.io`.

You can use `net.Socket` described here: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html which according to that doc is "is an abstraction of a TCP or UNIX socket".

A socket.io connection has a very specific startup protocol that it uses and a very specific over the wire data format and a very specific message sequence and a heatbeat keep-alive strategy.  Both ends must support all of that for a socket.io connection to work.

A plain socket is the root transport at the lowest level, but all this other stuff must exist on top of that plain socket for the two sides to be able to talk to one another using socket.io.  See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers) if you want a concise overview of what is involved in writing a webSocket server.  Socket.io is then another protocol on top of the webSocket transport.

---

Still very confused here.  I have no idea why you mention a standard Unix socket.

If you're trying to connect from one nodejs server to another nodejs server using socket.io and one of the servers is running the default socket.io server that you showed in your comments, then you should be able to do this from the other one to connect to the socket.io server:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://port.io');
socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on('event', function(data){});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

This assumes that `port.io` is the domain of your socket.io server (something that can be resolved with DNS to point to an actual server).  It's important that what you use must be an actual HTTP URL because all webSocket and socket.io connections are initiated with an HTTP request to an actual HTTP URL.

I don't follow what you're trying to do with Unix URL schemes.

Comment: why socket.io cares about lowest level protocol ?

Comment: I understand that I can connect using net.Socket, but why if I need to have socket.io event model ?

Comment: @eicto - You have to have something that speaks socket.io on BOTH ends for communication to work properly.  A plain Unix socket does not, by itself, know how to initiate a socket.io connection (which starts out as an HTTP request and is then upgraded to a webSocket) or know how to speak socket.io events.  You could get code to go on the Unix server that would speak socket.io and was listening on the port that you are going to connect and then you could use it.

Comment: still not undersand, why not use http connection and use `response.socket` to continue ws handshake.

Comment: @eicto - Is your server going to speak the webSocket and socket.io protocols?  If not, then you can't use socket.io to talk to it.  It's like if you are in spain and you only speak german and you want to make a collect call.  You HAVE to find an operator that speaks the same language as you do before you can make that call.  If you don't speak the same language, you can't communicate.

Comment: @eicto - I can't really tell where we're not understanding each other here.  I've added more to my answer that might help explain.

Comment: server is ok, because it created as 
`server = require('http').createServer(app);server.listen('port.io');`

I just can't connect to the server.

Comment: It is in question, but i checked code of socket.io-client and found that urlparser can't get unix schemes in any way, however Websocket object understand ws+unix:// scheme,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but since I came here looking for a similar answer, here is the code I came up with.

This code opens a unix domain socket, and broadcasts everything it receives to any connected socket.io clients (via WebSockets)

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.2
var app, domain_server, fs, io, net, server;
fs = require('fs');
net = require('net');
app = require('express')();
server = require('http').Server(app);
io = require('socket.io')(server);

/* Handle Unix Domain Socket
 * * Delete file if it already exists, 
 *   avoiding EADDRINUSE  */

if (fs.existsSync('/tmp/domain_socket')) {
  fs.unlinkSync('/tmp/domain_socket');
}

domain_server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    /* broadcast messages from unix socket to websockets */
    io.sockets.emit('domain-message', data.toString());
  });
});

domain_server.listen('/tmp/domain_socket', function() {
  console.log('domain_server bound');
});


/*
 * Handle Web Serving/WebSockets
 */

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('message', {
    hello: 'connected'
  });
});
```

Comment: What is bad with my  question ? 
this is not what I wanted, however, the question is to avoid tcp stack and use socket.io, o'c It is not the problem to send data received from unix socket or from file or whatever via socket.io established with tcp, o'c there is no problem to mimic solution, but for me it seems really strange that high level protocol implementation cares about it's transport.

Comment: mimic solution is not about your answer, it is about like "make localhost proxy"

Answer (score 0):

sure we can do it.

client side (in node 8.11, not in browser):

```
var pipe_name = '/tmp/your-pipe-name';
var channel_name = '/your-namespace';
var server_url = "ws+unix://" + pipe_name + channel_name;

var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var mock = require('mock-require');

class WebSockeMock extends WebSocket {
  constructor (address, protocols, options) {
    var uri = url.parse(server_url);
    var param = url.parse(address).search;
    address = "ws+unix:///" + uri.host + path.dirname(uri.pathname)
      + ":/socket.io/" + param;
    console.log("real ws", address)
    super(address, protocols, options);
  }
}

console.log("connecting to " + server_url);

if (/unix:\/+/.test(server_url)) {
  server_url = server_url.replace(/^[^:]+[:\/\\]+/, 'ws://');
  console.log("fake ws", server_url);
  mock('ws', WebSockeMock);
  process.env.DEBUG = '*';
}

var socket = require('socket.io-client')(server_url, {
  transports: ['websocket']
});

socket.on('connect', function() {
  return console.log("pipe connected");
});
```

server side:

```
var pipe_name = '/tmp/your-pipe-name';
var channel_name = '/your-namespace';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

if (fs.existsSync(pipe_name)) {
  fs.unlinkSync(pipe_name);
}
console.log("pipe server at " + pipe_name);
var io = require('socket.io')(require('http').createServer().listen(pipe_name));
var channel = io.of("/" + (path.basename(pipe_name)) + channel_name)
.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("unix pipe connected");
});
```

Comment: Did you tried this to run ? I see many syntax problems, like super not 1st, etc

Comment: Can you rewrite it on js ? Because to understand your answer one need to learn unnecessary technology.

Comment: OK, I changed :)

Comment: Will try tomorrow,